# Serializing a list of object as dictionnary in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, json, serialization, django-rest-framework

Using django & django-rest-framework, I have the following model (this is simplified but it's all there):

```
class Device(Model):
    #stuff

class DeviceInformation(Model):
    device = ForeignKey(Device, reverse='infos')
    key = CharField(max_length=32)
    value = CharField(max_length=1024)
```

When serializing a device through django-rest-framework's ModelSerializer, I get something like this:

```
{
    //stuff
    infos: [{
        'key':'BatteryLevel',
        'value':'80%'
    },{
        'key':'DeviceName',
        'value':'my device'
    }, //etc
    ]
}
```

Which is perfectly normal. However, it would make much more sense to serialize into something like this:

```
{
    //stuff
    infos: {
        'BatteryLevel':'80%',
        'DeviceName':'my device',
        //etc
    }
}
```

How do I do that? Is it even possible?
Note that I don't need to deserialize any of these information.

EDIT: my serializers are as follows:

```
class DeviceInfoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceInformation
        fields = ('key', 'value')
        read_only_fields = fields


class DeviceSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    udid = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, 'object') and self.object and not self.many:
            self.data['infos'] = DeviceInfoSerializer(
                self.object.infos.all(), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['udid', 'model', 'tracked']
        read_only_fields = ('model', 'tracked')
        slug_field = 'udid'
```

Comment: not an expert, what if you override the `get_field(..)` or `get_key_field()` and `get_value_field()`. see here http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#customising-the-default-fields

Comment: After inspecting the source, this won't work. However, by wrinting a custom `Field` and overwriting `to_native(...)` it should be possible to achieve this. I find this very hack-like however.

Comment: What do your serializers look like?

Answer (score 0):

For your readonly-case, the best way is to use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield).

This would change your `DeviceSerializer` and remove the need for your `DeviceInfoSerializer`.

```
class DeviceSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    udid = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    infos = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_infos')

    def get_infos(self, obj):
        return {
            info.key: info.value
            for info in obj.infos.all()
        }

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['udid', 'model', 'tracked', 'infos']
        read_only_fields = ('model', 'tracked', 'infos')
        slug_field = 'udid'
```